# Python Flask Server Not Working With Twilio

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I have been trying to create a personnel log using Raspberry Pi to record who is in the house and to respond to a Twilio text message and reply who is home. I'm using flask to form the server to Twilio however I am getting no response at all when I text the 'whoshome' query.  It should reply who is home, although only with one person assigned currently! Also Twilio should be sending a POST request to the predefined client in the dashboard to then ask for instructions upon receiving an SMS.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import thread
from twilio import twiml
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
import os
import logging
import twilio.twiml
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from flask import Flask, request, redirect

lcd_rs        = 21                                              #lcd setup
lcd_en        = 22
lcd_d4        = 25
lcd_d5        = 24
lcd_d6        = 23
lcd_d7        = 18
lcd_backlight = 4

lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows    = 4

lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight)

logging.basicConfig(filename='wifilog.log', level=logging.INFO) #logging setup

ACCOUNT_SID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"              #Twilio credentials setup
AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

user1status = 0                                                 #variables

def wifiping(): #check who is present
    while True:
        ret = os.system("ping -c 1 -s 1 192.168.1.118")
        lcd.clear()
        if ret != 0:
            lcd.message('Sam is not home')
            print "Sam is not home"
            logging.info('Sam not home at' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))
            user1status = 0
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            lcd.message('Sam is home')
            print "Sam is home"
            logging.info('Sam home at' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))
            user1status = 1
            time.sleep(5)

thread.start_new_thread(wifiping, ()) #new thread

r = twiml.Response()                  #Flask server setup
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods={'GET', 'POST'})
def whos_home():                           #Twilio message detection
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    if body == 'Whos home':
        if user1status == 0:
            r.message("Sam is not home.")
        elif user1status == 1:
            r.message("Sam is home.")
    else:
        pass
    return ' '

app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=80) #Flask app start
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with client... are you expecting it to magically know what to do? Or is Twilio supposed to be sending your client a GET/POST request? (also when you pasted it, your formatting got horked up with the markdown. Please [edit] your post and fix that)

Comment: @WayneWerner the Twilio docs gave the impression that it should be sending a POST request since it acts upon receiving a message (from my mobile phone) and then sends the POST request to the predefined server (as set in the dashboard) to ask what to do. Also I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean about the formatting?

Comment: look at `whos_home`. Is twilo sending post requests to your server?

Comment: @WayneWerner it is available to the outside world, it has been forwarded. Also the Flask client is used for receiving and then sending TwiML instructions, infact no server is needed at all to simply send messages, only to receive or to send TwiML instructions upon receiving. And yes I have done a tcp dump and I am receiving post requests from Twilio. The example code they provided uses exactly the same Flask server setup and it worked fine for me.

Comment: If twilio is actually POSTing to your server and you've verified that you're getting the request then your problem is either you're returning a bad response, or something else is going wrong on the twilio side

Comment: @WayneWerner I can't see where the bad response would be since its all standard TwiML library code, with no errors. And there is nothing wrong at their end since the example code they provide works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

It looks like you are returning an empty trying from your route:

```
return ' '
```

Since you've marked the route as accepting GET requests you can check this is what's happening by opening the public URL for this route in a browser and seeing what's returned.  You could also run a cURL request against the route to verify its returning what you expect.

I think you probably need to return the TwiML Response from the route instead of the empty string:

```
return str(r)
```

Hope that helps.